# Firebase Functions "External network is not accessible and quotas are severely limited" when calling Google maps API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I've a Firebase Function making a request to a Google API `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json` which should be allowed on the Spark plan because it's a Google API.

But in the logs it says this:

```
Billing account not configured. External network is not accessible and 
quotas are severely limited. Configure billing account to remove these 
restrictions
```

I found this weird because the Spark plan has this note for Cloud function:

```
The Spark plan allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned 
services. Inbound invocation requests are allowed within the quota.
```

The question here is: "is this a common issue or am I missing something here?"

Comment: There is no question here - and it sounds like a Google Support issue anyway.  I vote to close this off-topic question.

Comment: When your project is on the Spark/free plan, your Cloud Functions code is not allowed to make calls to services outside of the Google network. That's what the message is trying to say, although I must admit the wording is rather obtuse. The message shows up in the logs overly frequently, so it's more important of the call to maps fails or not. If it does, can you show the code that fails? That way we can check if you're doing something wrong.

Comment: `axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json', {params: params})` this is the call I am making